# Запятая перед словом "как"

Tags: пунктуация

> Я лучше знаю *как поступить*.

Нужна ли запятая перед словом *как*? Какое правило это регулирует?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Нужна ли запятая перед словом как?

НУЖНА.

> Какое правило это регулирует?

См. http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=134#pp134 :

> § 115...  Придаточная часть в сложноподчиненном предложении выделяется
>   запятыми с двух сторон, если стоит внутри главной части; **если же
>   придаточная часть стоит** перед главной частью или **после нее, то
>   отделяется от нее запятой.**

Плюс см. http://gramota.ru/spravka/buro/29_283044 :

> **Вопрос № 219988**
>
> Здравствуйте! Скажите, как правильно писать выражение "знаю как" с
>   запятой или без нее. И почему? Спасибо. Алёна
>
> **Ответ справочной службы русского языка**
>
> Союз "как" после слова "знаю" присоединяет придаточное предложение и,
>   соответственно, перед союзом ставится запятая. **Запятая не требуется
>   только в том случае, когда придаточное предложение состоит из одного
>   союза (иными словами, когда в придаточной части предложения после
>   "как" нет других слов).**